How to test two providers in Flutter / Riverpod?
I have 2 providers, Provider1 and Provider2, where Provider1 uses Provider2 in this way:
@riverpod
class Provider1Notifier extends _$Provider1Notifier with PersistenceHelper {

....

   void buy(int id) {
      final ProviderData data = getData(id);
      ...
   }

   ProviderData getData(int id) => ref.read(provider2NotifierProvider).firstWhere((g) => g.id == id);
}

In my test for Provider1, I have something like:
class MockProvider1Notifier extends Provider1Notifier {
  @override
  ProviderData build() {
    return ProviderData(
      ...
    );
  }
}

void main() {
  group('Provider1Notifier.init', ()
  {
    test('Do stuff...', () {
      final container = createContainer(overrides: [
        provider1NotifierProvider.overrideWith(() => MockProvider1Notifier()),
        provider2Provider1NotifierProvider.overrideWith(() => Provider2Notifier()),
      ]);

      Provider1Notifier notifier = container.read(provider1NotifierProvider.notifier);
      notifier.doSomething(0);
  ...
  }
 }
}

When I run the test I get the error:

UnimplementedError

which is pointing to the line of code:
ProviderData getData(int id) => ref.read(provider2NotifierProvider).firstWhere((g) => g.id == id);

and in particular to ref.read(provider2NotifierProvider).
I do not see more error description than that. Is there anything wrong with the test setting? How to fix that?
